# Trouble with Curry functions (SML/NJ)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, currying

> Often we are interested in computing f(i) i=m n∑ , the sum of function
>   values f(i) for i = m through n. Define ‘sigma f m n’ which computes
>   f(i) i=m n∑ . This is different from defining ‘sigma (f, m, n)’

I'm required to write a Curried version of this function. I'm have a bit of trouble understanding how this would actually work. I understand that a Curry function is something that takes in a function and produces a function. Would this be an example of a curry function?

```
fun myCurry f x = f(x)
```

As far as setting up my problem, would this be an acceptable start?

```
fun sigma f m n =
```

I haven't gotten any further, because I can't really grasp what i'm being asked to do.

Answer (score 12):

A curried function is not, in fact, a function that takes in a function and produces another function. That is a higher order function.

A curried function is simply one that takes more than one argument and can be partially applied by only giving it one of its arguments.

For example, with your sigma question,

```
fun sigma (f,m,n) = ...
```

is not a curried function, as it takes only one argument (the tuple `(f,m,n)`.)

```
fun sigma f m n = ...
```

, however, is a curried function, as it takes three arguments, and it is valid to say something like

```
val sigmasquare = sigma (fn x => x * x)
```

, partially applying sigma by giving it its first argument.

A simpler example would be

```
fun add (x,y) = x + y
```

This is a noncurried function. To evaluate it, you must give it its argument, which includes both `x` and `y`. `add (3,5)` will evaluate to 8, in this case.

```
fun add x y = x + y
```

is the curried version of this same function. This can be partially evaluated by just giving it `x`. For example, `add 3` will evaluate to a function which will add three to its argument.

This is more clearly seen by looking at the previous examples as anonymous or lambda functions.

The first is equivalent to `fn (x,y) => x + y`, which clearly takes two ints and evaluates to an int.

The second is equivalent to `fn x => fn y => x + y`, which takes an int and evaluates to a function taking another int and evaluating to an int.

Thus, the type of the first is `(int * int) -> int`, while the type of the second is `int -> int -> int`.

Hopefully, this clears currying up somewhat.

Comment: I'm still unclear on how I would apply it to my problem. I have to create multiple functions?

Comment: Yes, pattern matching in curried functions can be done in exactly the same way as in noncurried functions. (Also, note that they are called curried functions, not curry functions).

Comment: @qaphla How do I specify the types explicitly for your example `fun add x y`.  For example, I want `x` and `y` to be real, and in the function I round them before summing, and the `add` function returns an int.

Comment: Hi you can do that by specifying the result of the function to be real
Eg: add x y : real = x + y;